# T-SQL upload to FTP "Invalid Command" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

(The vendor environment prevents us from using SSIS for this solution so we are using T-SQL to get the FTP job done.)

There are many code samples for the FTP upload of files BUT I am not able to get passed an "Invalid Command" when I run the script. Does anyone have any idea?

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

-- sp_configure

DECLARE
@FTPServer varchar(128) ,
@FTPUser varchar(128) ,
@FTPPWD varchar(128) ,
@FTPPath varchar(128) ,
@FTPFileName varchar(128) ,
@SourcePath varchar(128) ,
@SourceFile varchar(128) ,
@workdir varchar(128),
@workfilename varchar(128),
@cmd varchar(1000)

SELECT @workfilename = 'ftpcmd.txt'

SET @workdir = 'E:\Extract\'
SET @FTPServer = 'ftp.blah.com'
SET @FTPUser = 'user1'
SET @FTPPWD = 'XXXXXXX'
SET @SourcePath = 'E:\ForOracleExtract\'
SET @SourceFile = 'test.txt'
SET @FTPPath = 'ftp://ftp.blah.com/directory/incoming/'
SET @FTPFileName = 'test.txt'

    -- deal with special characters for echo commands
select @FTPServer = replace(replace(replace(@FTPServer, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPUser = replace(replace(replace(@FTPUser, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPPWD = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPWD, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')
select @FTPPath = replace(replace(replace(@FTPPath, '|', '^|'),'<','^<'),'>','^>')

SELECT @cmd = 'echo ' + 'open ' + @FTPServer + ' > ' + @workdir + @workfilename
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPUser + '>> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT @cmd = 'echo ' + @FTPPWD + '>> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

select  @cmd = 'echo ' + 'ascii >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT @cmd = 'echo ' + 'put ' + @SourcePath + @SourceFile + ' ' + @FTPPath + @FTPFileName + ' >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT @cmd = 'echo ' + 'quit' + ' >> ' + @workdir + @workfilename
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT @cmd = 'ftp -s:' + @workdir + @workfilename
 -- Executing final step
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
GO
```

Comment: Here is the output verbage......Invalid Command, Not Connected, Not Connected, pswd, ascii, put ...blah blah, quit, NULL

Comment: what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: can you post your test.txt file (remove the password) ?

Comment: add `PRINT @cmd` before each `EXEC`.  look them over for obvious errors and even run them at the command line, one by one, to see what is going on.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a .bat file on the server and have the logic inside it? This could work quite well assuming your source / destination directory & server doesn't change (and this could be powershell script too. that could provide better error handling)

Comment: @mgrenier - the very first command 'echo open...' I have search for hours for a solution and there is nothing out there. Everyone has the script to FTP but no one has any solution for this 'invalid command' error that will not connect to the ftp site.

Comment: @JamesZ - thanks James, we have that batch file solution in place as a stop gap but we were hoping to get it to work in a sql job. The 'Invalid Command' is a mystery. Cannot find it anywhere related to T-sql. I'm sure it will be some simple config somewhere.